# Predicting discrete repeated measures using a discrete independent variable in SPSS?

Tags: time-series, anova, repeated-measures, spss, discrete-data

I have a discrete repeated measure (# of headaches in the past month) measured at time points 1 and 2, and a discrete independent variable measured at T1 (a score of 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, or 3). Time points 1 and 2 are pre and post-treatment (intervention) for headaches.

Usually, I would use a repeated measures test in SPSS for this, but I don't think I can if I have a discrete IV. My hypothesis is: "Having a higher score means that the treatment intervention is more effective, and therefore, participants with a higher score should have a larger decrease in headaches from T1 to T2 than those with a lower score."

What stat should I use to test my hypothesis? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Count variables are often modeled as generalized linear models using Poisson or negative binomial distributions with log links, which can be done in the GENLIN or GENLINMIXED procedures. GENLIN offers generalized estimating equations (GEE) methods to fit marginal or population-averaged models for repeated measures, while GENLINMIXED offers similar marginal models using a repeated specification, or subject-specific models using random effects.

In the menus, Analyze>Generalized Linear Models>Generalized Estimating Equations is the gateway into GENLIN for fitting GEE models, and Analyze>Mixed Models>Generalized Linear is the gateway into GENLINMIXED. Before trying this though, I suggest doing some reading in the area. *Applied Longitudinal Analysis* by Garrett Fitzmaurice, Nan Larird, and James Ware, has very good coverage of these kinds of models.